# JQuery Date Picker in ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I have a button in my page. When I click it, it should open a JQuery window.

Inside the window, I have a datepicker control, which by default should show the current date. My code is like so.

**CLIENT SIDE**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
      $("#<%= txtDate.ClientID %>").datepicker({
          changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: true,
          dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
          yearRange: '1901:2050',
          maxDate: new Date(),
          showOn: "button",
          buttonImage: "images/calendar.png",
          buttonImageOnly: true,
          showButtonPanel: true,
          showMonthAfterYear: true,
          inline: true,
          altField: "#<%= HiddenDate.ClientID %>",
          altFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
          onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
              shouldsubmit = true;
          },
          onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
              shouldsubmit = false;
              javascript: __doPostBack('<%= txtDate.ClientID %>', '');
          }
      });

Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(function (evt, args) {
        $("#<%= txtDate.ClientID %>").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
            yearRange: '1901:2050',
            maxDate: new Date(),
            showOn: "button",
            buttonImage: "images/calendar.png",
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            showButtonPanel: true,
            showMonthAfterYear: true,
            inline: true,
            altField: "#<%= HiddenDate.ClientID %>",
            altFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
            onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
                shouldsubmit = true;
            },
            onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
                shouldsubmit = false;
                javascript: __doPostBack('<%= txtDate.ClientID %>', '');
            }
        });
    });
```

**SERVER SIDE**

```
If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        TxtDate.Text = DateTime.Today.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")
        TxtDate.Text = Session("CurrentDate")
End If
```

But the textbox remains blank. Any clues as to where I am wrong?

Comment: did you try to print Session("CurrentDate") ? AS you are setting it from session if it doesn't have valid date in correct format it will blank out.

Comment: @Sumit, The problem is my page is getting posted back. So the breakpoint which I had set in my above code doesn't let me go into the IF loop.

Comment: Are you missing the value First time or there after ?

Comment: @Sumit, the textbox is blank the first time the page loads.

Comment: You setting the `TxtDate's` Text value to Today and right after that re-setting it to `CurrentDate` value from Session. Should the second line must be `Session("CurrentDate") = TxtDate.Text`? Or even better like that: `Session("CurrentDate") = TxtDate.Text = DateTime.Today.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue.

The problem was I had reset the date on click of the Add button in my code. Hence it didn't show the date. So I removed the following code from the page load block and added it to the Add button click event after I reset the date.

```
Protected Sub btnNewBatch_Click(sender As Object, e As ImageClickEventArgs) Handles btnNewBatch.Click
    TxtDate.Text = DateTime.Today.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")
    TxtDate.Text = Session("CurrentDate")
    HiddenDate.Value = TxtDate.Text
End Sub
```

Thanks @Samit and @Yuriy for your time and suggestions!