# Date picker for ASP.NET 4.0 application

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have an ASP.NET/C# 4.0 application. I want a date picker icon to appear in the text box. On clicking the textbox web control I want the date picker to show.

I want to minimize code at this point but yet display a decent look and feel with the date picker.

Comment: BTW this is not a solution which I am looking for :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19087484/jquery-date-picker-in-asp-net?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Try using Bootstrap instead. http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/. You just need to download the .js file and import it to make it work.

Here is the sample code

```
<div class="input-append date" id="dpYears" data-date="2008-12-31"
data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd" data-date-viewmode="years"> <asp:TextBox
ID="txtBirthday" runat="server" Width="175px"></asp:TextBox> <span
class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span></div>
```